# Is the Odd-even topology weakly countably compact?

Tags: general-topology

Something eludes me in the proof that the odd-even topology is weakly countable compact found here :

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Odd-Even_Topology_is_Weakly_Countably_Compact

I don't understand why is $x$ a limit of point $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument given at that link is incorrect as stated, though I can see what was intended. Let me give you a corrected version.

Let $x\in A$. If $x$ is even, let $y=x-1$, and if $x$ is odd, let $y=x+1$. Let $B=\{x,y\}$; in both cases $B$ is open. Now let $U$ be any open nbhd of $y$. Then necessarily $B\subseteq U$, so $x\in A\cap\big(U\setminus\{y\}\big)$. That is, every open nbhd of $y$ contains a point of $A$ different from $y$, so be definition $y$ is a limit point of $A$. $A$ was an arbitrary infinite subset of $S$, so $S$ is weakly countably compact.

In fact the argument shows that *every* non-empty subset of $S$ has a limit point, not just every *infinite* subset.

Comment: Very enlightening, thank you!

Comment: Am I right in saying that the limits points of $A := \{1, 3, 5, 7,...\}$ are $\{2, 4, 6, 8, ...\}$ ? And that the sequence  1, 3, 5, 7, ...  as no converging subsequence (thus showing that this topological space is not sequentially compact) ?

Comment: @M.G: You’re welcome! Yes, the limit points of the set of odd positive integers are the even positive integers. And yes, $\langle 1,3,5,\ldots\rangle$ has no convergent subsequence. In fact $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ is convergent iff there are $m,n\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $x_k\in\{2m-1,2m\}$ whenever $k\ge n$, and in that case it converges both to $2m-1$ and to $2m$.